# How to use Swift closure in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, closures, block

I create a swift file in the product. my swift file like this:

```
import UIKit
typealias handler = (String?, Bool?)->Void

@objc  class godness: NSObject {

var test:String?
func sad()->String?
{
    test = "adfasdfaf"
    return test
}

func testX(sss:String?, xx:String?)
{

}

func godnessGetData(hander:handler)
{
    var str:String = ""
    let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

    let para = ["section_id":"1",
    "type":"json"];

    manager.POST("http://api.xxx.com/xxx.php",
        parameters: para,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            str = "JSONsssss:  \(responseObject.description)"
            hander(str, false)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            str = "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"

    })
}
}
```

but in the ProductName-Swift.h don't have godnessGetData. 
the ProductName-Swift.h like this:

```
@interface godness : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * __nullable test;
- (NSString * __nullable)sad;
- (void)testX:(NSString * __nullable)sss xx:(NSString * __nullable)xx;
- (SWIFT_NULLABILITY(nonnull) instancetype)init 
@end
```

I don't know whether Objective C can use swift closure.
sorry for my poor english.

Comment: You can add `@objc` to the method to force an error message. Basically ObjC doesn't support optional value types (`Bool?`). If you change it to just `Bool` it should work.

Comment: Thanks  for tipping about the `@objc`! I didn't know it can be used with properties too.